# Navicat Filter feature works faster than queries? how is it?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, navicat

I'm running a query on a view. When I run the query using the query feature of the navicat, it returns 25 seconds, but when I try using the filter feature, the result returns in 3.5 seconds.
I tried the query that comes to the mysql server when the filter feature works in mysql logs. the result is 25 seconds again. I checked if it does navicat caching on the view. but when I update a data in the tables to which the view is linked, the result is consistent. I think filters don't do caching.

How can the filter feature get results very quickly?

Comment: Well, you can try to use pagination, to return less itens on each query to database.

Comment: only one record, limit 1.
How does the navicat filtering feature work faster?

Comment: the problem was not that the filtering was fast. query feature was running very slow.
When I tried it with mysql workbench and phpMyadmin the query ran in 3.5 seconds. however, the navicat query runs very slowly. navicat query feature  misled.

Comment: Can you show us the SQL generated in each case?